# Clion and cmake compile error

Tags: cmake, mingw, clion

I'm trying to set up an environment using Clion with Cmake and MinGW. I configure in clion but when I refresh I get the error down below. I should mention that I am new to C/C++ but I've followed instructions on setting up required things but for some reason it doesn't work. What I'm trying to edit is a fork of the vox engine. I've searched for the error but none of what has helped me.

I've tried setting the path C:\MinGW\bin, moving the working directory somewhere without spaces in the name. There's other things I have tried as well but can't remember specifically.

```
"D:\Gustav Olsson\Program\CLion 2016.3.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" "D:\Gustav Olsson\Programming\Voxel"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_f8fdc/fast"
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at D:/Gustav Olsson/Program/CLion 2016.3.2/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: D:/Gustav Olsson/Programming/Voxel/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_f8fdc/fast"



  Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was:
  "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_f8fdc/fast"





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Gustav Olsson/Programming/Voxel/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Gustav Olsson/Programming/Voxel/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

EDIT:
Last lines from output CMakeOutput.log

```
Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "D:/Gustav Olsson/Programming/Voxel/CMakeFiles/3.6.3/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0
```

output CMakeError.log

```
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/Gustav Olsson/Programming/Voxel/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_ae556/fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_ae556/fast"


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/Gustav Olsson/Programming/Voxel/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_f8fdc/fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_f8fdc/fast"


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/Gustav Olsson/Programming/Voxel/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_3f00c/fast"

Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_3f00c/fast"
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: `I'm trying to set up an environment using Clion with Cmake and MinGW.` - But you call `cmake` for generate **CodeBlocks** project: `-G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"`. There are "See also" lines at the end of the output you show. Have you seen into these files? Add content of file `D:/Gustav Olsson/Programming/Voxel/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log` into your question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the reply, I posted the outputs of the files, How do I change ' -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" ' to Clion instead of CodeBlocks?

Comment: There's no generator for Clion in the sense you probably imagine, even in the latest CMake, so you CANNOT change for example (I think you imagine doing this) `-G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"` to `-G "Clion - MinGW Makefiles"`!

Comment: So there is no way to have Clion compile/run until a generator supports Clion?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and installed mingw-14.1 from [mingw-14.1](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html#install) over my already existing MinGW and that removed the error with compiling the test file